# How to access database items with dynamic URLs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

How do I make my website that if I went to the url 'mywebsite.com/1/', it would show a database item with the id of '1'? All the tutorials I have found are for setting up 'urls.py' in the older versions of Django, but not how to make dynamic urls.

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class video (models.Model):

    VID_CHOICES = (
        ('News', 'News'),
        ('Stam', 'Stam'),
        ('Music', 'Music'),
        ('Ad', 'Ad'),
    )
    
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    show_after_time = models.DateTimeField('show after')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=VID_CHOICES)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Have you looked at the current version of the documentation…? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a path that accepts a parameter, like:

```
path('<int:pk>/', some_view, name='some_view'),
```

In the *`some_view`*, there is then an extra parameter **`pk`** that will take the value entered in the path as `int`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def some_view(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'app_name/some_template.html', {'item': item})
```

then in the template, you can render the the (attributes) of the `item`:

```
{{ item }}
```